# How to avoid repetitiveness with the same nested key values in JSON file

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a rather algorithmic question. As given in the json example there are several nested keys with the same name (`services`). Current `parseData` function is simply looping through the `services` and it only goes as deep as the fourth nest.

I'm only interested in the `name` key's value within `services` array, but also need the id to keep track of things (e.g. when this id is pressed in table View display the corresponding title). I know this can be solved using a recursive function, but I just don't know how to start as the first for loop has slightly different structure (e.g. the first nest doesn't have an `id` key). Ultimately `name` key values will be fed into Tableview e.g. `Title 1` and `Title 2` will be displayed if `id` property is `nil`.

**I have two questions:**
**1)** This rather non-elegant code is not working at the moment. I have spent hours trying to fix what's wrong with it, if not days, but no success so far.

`serviceName` is getting printed as expected, but `serviceMain.count` is printing zero, that means serviceMain is empty?! I have put the code from viewDidLoad (commented out code) to didSet, otherwise `serviceMain` wasn't getting updated in time and tableView was empty (list of names, the code is too long now anyway, so removed the tableView bit), didSet did the trick initially, but I might have changed something and it doesn't work anymore. **What is wrong with my code please?**

**2)** Could you suggest a solution how to make this code more elegant and effective using recursive function etc? The same JSON structure could be a lot deeper (services array existing in 10 folds etc), I have only provided the following JSON as an example. Many Thanks for reading and hopefully you will be able to help!

**JSON data** (simplified and given as `path = "http://example.com/services"`

```
{
  “Provider1”: {
    "name": “Provider1”,
    "services": [
      {
        "id": “901”,
        "name": “Title 1”,
        "services": [
          {
            "id": “950”,
            "name": “Title 1A”,
            "services": []
          },
          {
            "id": “951”,
            "name": “Title 1B”,
            "services": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "970”,
        "name": “Title 2”,
        "services": [
          {
            "id": “971”,
            "name": “Title 2A”,
            "services": [          {
                "id": “972”,
                "name": “Subtitle 21A”,
                "services": []
              },
              {
                "id": “973”,
                "name": “Subtitle 21B”,
                "services": []
          }]
          },
          {
            "id": “974”,
            "name": “Title 2B”,
            "services": []
          }
        ]},
  “Provider2”: {...
    ...
```

}

**Service.swift:**

```
import UIKit

struct Service {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

    enum SerializationError: Error {
        case missing(String)
        case invalid(String, Any)
    }

    init(json: [String: Any]) throws {
        guard let id = (json["id"] as? NSString)?.integerValue else { throw SerializationError.missing("id is missing")}
        guard let name = json["name"] as? String else { throw SerializationError.missing("name is missing")}
    }

    static let path = "http://example.com/services"

    static func parseData(providerName: String, id: Int? = nil, completion: @escaping ([Service]) -> ()) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: path)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

            var services: [Service] = []
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

                    // A. Main Array
                    guard let jsonArray = json as? [String: Any],
                        let providerMain = jsonArray[providerName] as? [String: Any],
                        let servicesMain = providerMain["services"] as? [Any] else {
                            return
                    }

                    // B. First nest
                    for service1 in servicesMain {
                        guard let service11 = service1 as? [String: Any],
                            let service12 = service11["services"] as? [Any],
                            let service11Id = (service11["id"] as? NSString)?.integerValue else {
                                return
                        }
                        if let subServices = try? Service(json: service11), id == nil {
                            services.append(subServices)
                        }

                    // C. Second nest
                        for service2 in service12 {
                            guard let service21 = service2 as? [String:Any],
                                let service22 = service21["services"] as? [Any],
                                let service21Id = (service21["id"] as? NSString)?.integerValue else {
                                    return
                            }

                            if let subServices = try? Service(json: service21), service11Id == id {
                                services.append(subServices)
                            }

                    // D. Third nest
                            for service3 in service22 {
                                guard let service31 = service3 as? [String:Any],
                                    let service32 = service31["services"] as? [Any],
                                    let service31Id = (service31["id"] as? NSString)?.integerValue else {
                                        return
                                }

                                if let subServices = try? Service(json: service31), service21Id == id {
                                    services.append(subServices)
                                }
                    // E. Fourth nest
                                for service4 in service32 {
                                    guard let service41 = service4 as? [String:Any] else {
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if let subServices = try? Service(json: service41), service31Id == id {
                                        services.append(subServices)
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                completion(services)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var serviceMain: [String] = [] {
        didSet{
            Service.parseData(providerName: "Provider1", id: nil) { (services: [Service]) in
                for service in services {
                    guard let serviceName = service.name else { return }
                    self.serviceMain.append(serviceName)
                    print(serviceName)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
// Below commented out code also produced zero count in serviceMain        
// Service.parseData(providerName: "Provider1", id: nil) { (services: [Service]) in
//            for service in services {
//                guard let serviceName = service.name else { return }
//                self.serviceMain.append(serviceName)
//                print(serviceName)
//            }
//        }
        print("serviceMain count: \(serviceMain.count)")
    }


}
```

Comment: anyone would like to chip in please?

Answer (score 0):

For JSON parser you can use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper).

In your case, for example,

```
class ProviderWrapper: Mappable{
    var provider1: Provider?
    var provider2: Provider?
    .....
}

class Provider: Mappable{
    var name: String?
    var services: [Service]?
}

class Service: Mappable{

   var id: Int?
   var name: String?
   var services: [Service]?
}
```